# What's the best way to block a thread during a test to check it's state?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Testing in Java (using Mockito and Powermock but willing to use anything that will solve this). I have an object that has the following signature:

```
public class MyClass {
   public void doRun() {
      //Do work
   }

   public int numberComplete() {
      //Return number of items complete
   }
}
```

The "doRun" method gets a list of items and "completes" them (each taking a considerable amount of time). In order to "get" and "finish" an item, a mock manager is used, so I have tests like:

```
@Test public void managerIsInformedOfEachFinishedItem() {
  task.doRun();
  verify(mockManager, times(3)).finish((Item)any());
}
```

At the end of this, I can call "task.numberComplete()" and see that indeed, the task returns 3. But, what I'd really like to do is something like:

```
@Test public void managerIsInformedOfEachFinishedItem() {
  int count1, count2;
  when(mockManager.finish(item1).thenSet(count1 = task.numberComplete());
  when(mockManager.finish(item2).thenSet(count2 = task.numberComplete());

  task.doRun();

  assertEquals(1, count1);
  assertEquals(2, count2);
}
```

I realize this may not be something that's already available. But if you were going to try to implement something like this (regardless of the syntax - I don't care how clean the test reads initially), how would you do it? Any suggestions/ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a third-party mock framework for the manager, you could implement your own mock manager that does the verification for you in its `finish` method. Bear in mind that if `finish` will get called in a different thread, then you shouldn't put the `assertEquals` there because an `AssertionError` thrown in that thread will most likely be ignored. Instead, you could store the success/failure result in a member variable (property) of your mock manager and check that from your test afterward. (Don't forget to synchronize access to that shared result value or use an [atomic](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) to hold it.)